# Error in JavaScript code while attempting to make the button submit the form

Tags: javascript

This is code which should perform a submission on a form, but it doesn't do the submission:

```
 <script>
  function validate(){
   var formm = document.getElementById('form_first');
   var basar1=document.form_first.basar1;
   var basar2=document.form_first.basar2;
   if(basar1.checked == 1 && basar2.checked == 1){     
   alert('Please ckeck only one of them') ;            
    }
   else{
    formm.submit();
    }    
      }
  </script>
```

And this is my HTML page:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="form_first" id="form_first" >

 <tr id="row_ques">
     <td width="200">aaaaa</td>
     <td width="113"><input type="checkbox" name="basar1" value="aaaa" /></td>
     <td width="113"><input type="checkbox" name="basar2" value="bbbb" /></td>
  </tr>

<input type="button"  onclick="validate();" value="Save" name="btn_first" id="btn_first"  />

</form>
```

the problem is that the form isn't submitted if validation checked correctlly

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: where do you want to submit the form? to "#"? `action="#"` might be the problem. everything is fine with HTML and JavaScript at my side!

Comment: Why do you get `formm` through `document.getElementById`, but when getting its inputs, you look up the form again via `document.formm` (twice)?

Comment: `basar1.checked == 1` is bad. `basar1.checked` is a boolean, not a number. You should drop `== 1`.

Comment: If you want at most one checkbox checked, why aren't you using radio buttons?

Comment: Your edit still doesn't reply to "are you getting any errors?". Please open the developer console (`F12` or `CTRL+SHIFT+J`) and read us what's there or tell us if nothing is.

Comment: no errors occurs . it still on the same page . but no data comming from the form . i.e the form doesn't submit

Comment: Could you share how you are handling the form submission? PHP, PERL, Python, etc. Please post your code.

Comment: Paste your entire PHP file in the question.

Comment: @vivekvasani given no submission seems to happen, how can the server code affect anything?

Comment: @JanDvorak, just wondering if the form submission is even being handled at all.

Comment: @vivekvasani not sure it's relevant to the question, but w/e. I'm always happy to point out the obvious flaws in someone's code.

Comment: when i remove the type from the input it works correctly !!

Comment: <input onclick="validate();" value="حـــفــــظ" name="btn_first" id="btn_first"  /> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh m3lsh ya 2bo mostafa .... oltlk hytshal !!! @user3148167

Comment: ههههههههههههه والله فعلا شلته وشغال من غيره اه :(

Answer (score 1):

Posting to hash `"#"` doesn't trigger a page load. Posting to `""` will load the page with the post data.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form_first" id="form_first" >

 <tr id="row_ques">
     <td width="200">aaaaa</td>
     <td width="113"><input type="checkbox" name="basar1" value="aaaa" /></td>
     <td width="113"><input type="checkbox" name="basar2" value="bbbb" /></td>
  </tr>

  <input type="button"  onclick="validate();" value="Save" name="btn_first" id="btn_first"  />

</form>
```

Cleaned up JS:

```
function validate(){
    var formm = document.getElementById('form_first');
    if(formm.basar1.checked && formm.basar2.checked ){     
        alert('Please ckeck only one of them');            
    }else{
        formm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3148167, where are you trying to post the form to? What is the expected action?

Comment: if you are using PHP, post the form to `""` instead of `"#"`

Comment: @vivekvasani please move the clarification request thread to the question, where it belongs.

Comment: @user3148167 it does; `#` on the other hand means "stay on the page", at least in a `href`.

Comment: oK. is the code is correct ? why it doesn;t submit the form ?

Comment: @user3148167 `formm.submit` respects the `action`, which says "stay on the page". That's why.

Comment: @user3148167 define (in the question) "not working". This includes any error messages shown by the browser in the error log / developer console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSubmit` function to validate the form

```
<form action="/feedback" method="post" name="form_first" 
       onSubmit="return validate()">
     <!-- write your form conent -->
</form> 


function validate(){
    //validation
    if (failed) {
        // return false will cancel the form submission
        return false;
    }   

    // If everything goes well, proceed the form submission
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change these lines

```
   var basar1=document.form_first.basar1;
       var basar2=document.form_first.basar2;
```

to

```
var basar1=formm.getElementById('basar1');
var basar2=formm.getElementById('basar1');
```

and you should be through

Comment: but the validation is working  correctly

the problem is in submitting the form

Comment: firstly, his inputs don't have an ID. so, you can't search them by ID.

Comment: What's wrong with `document.form_first.basar1`? Sure `document.forms.form_first.basar1` might have been better but either works just fine.

Comment: mmmmmm concenterate only withe my problem

Comment: oh, and a typo. You're looking up the same ID twice.

Comment: my problem is that the form not submitted if validation is true :(

Comment: @user3148167 you should say this _within the question_, not as a comment (to an answer, moreover)

Comment: @user3148167 _always_ include as much relevant information as you can within the question. This applies on any Q/A site, not just Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user3148167 you were also asked "what errors are you getting" to which you haven't replied yet. Please check the error log and edit your question appropriately.